# I uninstalled my ubuntu 14.04 desktop now i have no login in screen

Tags: 14.04, login, lamp, tasksel

I followed instructions [here](http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/) to use `sudo  tasksel` to install a LAMP server as a one line command

however i overlooked what was actually happening and removed my desktop environment.

When i reboot i am faced with a kind of loading screen that switched purple to black and never gives me a login screen.

I can access the command line

```
Ctrl + Alt + F2
```

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This worked up to a point where it is unable to fetch things from online, as far as i know the system should be online ,

Do i have to reinstall the OS or is there a easy way around this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to repair your installation with a live usb, the Ubuntu installer has an option to repair your installation, instead of just reinstalling everything.